# Lightning Web Component display title track

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-web-components

Hi I have a req on which i want to set the property on parent component and as Yes and no and pass it to child component ..and on the basis of the Yes i need to display the title in the HTML markup of the child component. 
 @api titltrack is an property received from the user by MetaXMl file

Parent JS

```
export default class ASDFG extends LightningElement{
   @api titleTrack
 }
```

Parent HTML

```
  <template>
      <c-childcmp title-track={titleTrack}></childcmp>
  </template
```

Child JS

```
export default class gfgtryf extends LightningElement{
    @api titleTrack
    @track stTryf
settitlehjy(){
  if(this.titleTrack === 'Yes')
    this.stTryf = 'HTML title';

*if titleTrack is having the value as Yes then set the title child cmp of the HTMl as "HTML title"
         }
}
```

Child HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title={stTryf }>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you tell what exactly is the problem, what did you expect to happen and what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `settitlehjy` is never get called until you call it explicitly.
Use the getter method to get the value in your child component.

Instead of the `stTryf`. **Always use meaningful variable names like htmlTitle, title etc**

Getter methods execute automatically whenever the referred properties are changed.

```
get htmlTitle(){
    return this.titleTrack === 'Yes' ? 'HTML title' : '';
}
```

use it in HTML of the child.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title={htmlTitle}>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```